# Two Texts on a Single Button in Android?

Tags: android, android-button

I have a button in Android Studio:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Event Name (23)" />
```

It looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------
| Event Name (23)                   |
-------------------------------------
```

What I would like is two pieces of text in a single button.

Basically, I want on the left side of the button, the name of an event... then I want on the right side of the button to have the number of people registered for the event, so it looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------
| Event Name                   (23) |
-------------------------------------
```

Is something like this possible?

I am completely new to Android, so keep that in mind.

Comment: check `SpannableString `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Layout instead of Button and Then perform click event on layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Event Name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="(23)"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Activity :

```
RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayout);

        relLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Implement Your login on RelativeLayout click
            }
        });
```

Comment: How would I then make the layout look like a button? And have the same reactions as a button... like the fades/flashes it has when you click/hold the button.

Comment: You can create drawable xml file based on your need and set as background to layout.

Comment: You will find many tutorials and posts on internet regarding this

Answer (score 2):

pls try this

```
  <RelativeLayout 
   android:id="@+id/btn"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#ff0000"
   android:padding="10dp"
   >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Event Name " />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="(23)" />
```

Comment: How would I then make the layout look like a button? And have the same reactions as a button... like the fades/flashes it has when you click/hold the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a layout to show two text in it.And you can add the listener in the layout.

Comment: But then it doesn't look like a button... how would I get the layout to look like it was a button; follow the app's theme and have the same sort of responses, like when you click on a button and the button flashes.

Comment: You set the background of the button to a selector and have different drawables for the different states.   The drawables can be shapes with rounded corners.

Comment: You can write a drawable.Like this:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/item_grey" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/item_grey" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/item_grey" />
<item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>

Comment: Pls edit your answer and post code in this, it'll clean and easy to view

Answer (score 1):

use spannable strings

```
String text;
SpannableString finalText = new SpannableString(text);
finalText.setSpan((new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE), <start index of right String>, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
button.setText(finalText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a file named item_color_grey.xml in you drawable directory.The code is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/item_grey" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/item_grey" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/item_grey" />
     <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way to do whatever you need.
in your layout define button like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/lay_back"
    >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Event Name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textSize="26sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="(23)"
    android:textSize="26sp"/>
```

And in Your drawable folder create a xml file lay_back.xml and write below code into it.

For ripple effect:(For Higher API levels)

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:color="@color/white">
     <item android:drawable="@color/item_grey"/>
     </ripple>
```

For Selector Effect(Lower APIs) :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/item_grey"       />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"      android:drawable="@color/item_dark_grey" />
 <item android:drawable="@color/item_grey" />
  </selector>
```

You can Give Any color stored in colors.xml of values directory.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this post is pretty old. I've found a solution to it is by having Two buttons inside a relative layout.

Button1 having text left align (clickable=false) and stylesheet of a button.

Button2 having text right align (clickable=true) and stylesheet of a button; and having background transperent.

catch on the Activity Side, one will have to handle enable and disable state for both these button. While handling the click for the main button only.

Let me know if someone is look out for similar solution; in which case I can post the sample code.